# When a new row is added input name goes up by 1?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a button to add a row to my table.

I would like the input name on the 3 textboxes to go up by 1 when the row clones.

This is the script I'm using now. (it clones the row and adds it underneath, but it doesn't +1 the input name.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function() {
$('#mytable tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#mytable tbody>tr:last');
$('#mytable tbody>tr:last #product').val('');
    $('#mytable tbody>tr:last #qty').val('');
        $('#mytable tbody>tr:last #remarks').val('');
            $('#mytable tbody>tr:last #add').val('+');
return false;
    });
});
```

This is my Table

```
 <table id="mytable" width="250px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"  style="text-align:center; padding-left:40px; padding-bottom:8px">
   <tr class="product">
   <td style="text-align:center;"><strong>Item</strong></td>
   <td style="text-align:center;"><strong>Qty.</strong></td>
   <td style="text-align:center;"><strong>Remarks</strong></td>
   </tr>
   <tr name="product" class="product">
   <td width="100px"><input type="text" width="100px" name="product" id="product" /></td>
   <td width="5px" style="text-align:center; padding-left:2px; padding-right:2px;"><input type="text" width="5px" size="1" maxlength="2" name="qty" id="qty" /></td>
   <td width="100px"><input type="text" width="100px" name="remarks" id="remarks" /></td>
   <td><input type="submit" name="add" id="add" value="+" /></td>
   </tr>
   </table>
```

The question is: How would I have the input names "product" "qty" "remarks" change to "product1" "qty1" "remarks1" on the next row? And 2 on the row after 3 on row after that to infinite amount of rows.

Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: Please consider posting a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for us to experiment with, and see (a relevant excerpt of) your script, and HTML, working.

Answer (score 2):

The following seems to work, added to your `click()` handler:

```
    $('#mytable tbody > tr:last input').each(
        function(){
            /* the following removes the numerical characters from the id */
            var id = this.id.replace(/[0-9]+/g,'');
            /* this iterates through each id that starts with the same sequence
               of characters */
            $('input[id^=' + id + ']').each(
                function(i){
                    /* this sets the id to the sequence of characters,
                       plus the number of the current iteration of the
                       each() method */
                    this.id = id + i;
                });
        });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WMvRJ/3/).

---

**Edited** in response to comment from the OP (below):

> ...But the id goes up by 1 I need the input name to go up by 1. How would I change this to increase"name"?

You can do that easily enough, just make the `name` equal to the `id` in the inner `each()` call:

```
    $('#mytable tbody > tr:last input').each(
        function(){
            /* the following removes the numerical characters from the id */
            var id = this.id.replace(/[0-9]+/g,'');
            /* this iterates through each id that starts with the same sequence
               of characters */
            $('input[id^=' + id + ']').each(
                function(i){
                    /* this sets the id to the sequence of characters,
                       plus the number of the current iteration of the
                       each() method */
                    this.id = id + i;
                    this.name = this.id;
                });
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WMvRJ/4/

References:

- [attribute starts-with selector: `^=`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).
- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [RegExp, at the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).
- [`replace()`, at the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: Hey, that works really well. But the id goes up by 1 I need the input name to go up by 1. How would I change this to increase"name"?

Comment: Just edited the answer to address that concern, my apologies: I should've thought of that myself, really. =/

Answer (score 0):

You could either have a global variable in javascript keep track of the row number, or you could use javascript to parse the previous row's number. I would personally use a global variable.